# Create (efficiently) fake truth/predicted values from a confusion matrix

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, confusion-matrix

For testing purpose I need to create fake truth/predicted values from a confusion matrix.

My confusion matrix is stored in a Pandas DataFrame using:

```
labels = ['N', 'L', 'R', 'A', 'P', 'V']
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1971, 19, 1, 8, 0, 1],
    [16, 1940, 2, 23, 9, 10],
    [8, 3, 181, 87, 0, 11],
    [2, 25, 159, 1786, 16, 12],
    [0, 24, 4, 8, 1958, 6],
    [11, 12, 29, 11, 11, 1926] ], columns=labels, index=labels)
df.index.name = 'Actual'
df.columns.name = 'Predicted'
```

I assume indexes are actual values, and columns are predicted values.

This confusion matrix looks like:

```
Predicted     N     L    R     A     P     V
Actual
N          1971    19    1     8     0     1
L            16  1940    2    23     9    10
R             8     3  181    87     0    11
A             2    25  159  1786    16    12
P             0    24    4     8  1958     6
V            11    12   29    11    11  1926
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to create 2 Numpy arrays: `y_true` and `y_predict` which will product such a confusion matrix.

My first idea was first create Numpy arrays of the good size.

So I did:

```
N_all = df.sum().sum()

y_true = np.empty(N_all)
y_pred = np.empty(N_all)
```

but I don't know exactly how to fill efficiently these 2 Numpy array

Same code should also apply to a binary confusion matrix like:

```
labels = [False, True]
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [5, 3],
    [2, 7]], columns=labels, index=labels)
df.index.name = 'Actual'
df.columns.name = 'Predicted'
```

This binary confusion matrix looks like:

```
Predicted  False  True
Actual
False          5      3
True           2      7
```

Comment: So, you have the matrix as input and need to generate both vectors y_true and y_predicted?  The values with same label should have same values in both vectors. The values with distinct label should be pushed to each vector as their predicted/true value. I think I missed the question in this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exactly recreate you can use the following function:

```
def create_arrays(df):
    # Unstack to make tuples of actual,pred,count
    df = df.unstack().reset_index()

    # Pull the value labels and counts
    actual = df['Actual'].values
    predicted = df['Predicted'].values
    totals = df.iloc[:,2].values

    # Use list comprehension to create original arrays
    y_true = [[curr_val]*n for (curr_val, n) in zip(actual, totals)]
    y_predicted = [[curr_val]*n for (curr_val, n) in zip(predicted, totals)]

    # They come nested so flatten them
    y_true = [item for sublist in y_true for item in sublist]
    y_predicted = [item for sublist in y_predicted for item in sublist]

    return y_true, y_predicted
```

We can check that this produces the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

labels = ['N', 'L', 'R', 'A', 'P', 'V']
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1971, 19, 1, 8, 0, 1],
    [16, 1940, 2, 23, 9, 10],
    [8, 3, 181, 87, 0, 11],
    [2, 25, 159, 1786, 16, 12],
    [0, 24, 4, 8, 1958, 6],
    [11, 12, 29, 11, 11, 1926] ], columns=labels, index=labels)
df.index.name = 'Actual'
df.columns.name = 'Predicted'

# Recreate the original confusion matrix and check for equality
y_t, y_p = create_arrays(df)
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_t,y_p)
check_labels = np.unique(y_t)

df_new = pd.DataFrame(conf_mat, columns=check_labels, index=check_labels).loc[labels, labels]
df_new.index.name = 'Actual'
df_new.columns.name = 'Predicted'

df == df_new
```

Output:

```
Predicted     N     L     R     A     P     V
Actual                                       
N          True  True  True  True  True  True
L          True  True  True  True  True  True
R          True  True  True  True  True  True
A          True  True  True  True  True  True
P          True  True  True  True  True  True
V          True  True  True  True  True  True
```

And for the Binary:

```
# And for the binary
labels = ['False', 'True']
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [5, 3],
    [2, 7]], columns=labels, index=labels)
df.index.name = 'Actual'
df.columns.name = 'Predicted'

# Recreate the original confusion matrix and check for equality
y_t, y_p = create_arrays(df)
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_t,y_p)
check_labels = np.unique(y_t)

df_new = pd.DataFrame(conf_mat, columns=check_labels, index=check_labels).loc[labels, labels]
df_new.index.name = 'Actual'
df_new.columns.name = 'Predicted'

df == df_new

Predicted False  True
Actual               
False      True  True
True       True  True
```

Comment: You might add `df_comp = df != df_new` and `assert df_comp.sum().sum()==0` but it doesn't work with binary `Predicted  False  True
Actual
False          5      3
True           2      7
Predicted  True
Actual
True          7`

Comment: y_true array can be create using `sum_true = df.sum(axis=1).shift(1).fillna(0)
    sum_predicted = df.sum(axis=0).shift(1).fillna(0)

    index = np.arange(N_all)
    s_true = pd.Series(index=index)

    s_true[sum_true] = sum_true.index
    s_true = s_true.fillna(method='ffill')
    y_true = s_true.values` but I still don't see how to create y_predicted efficiently. I'm using Pandas Series but pure Numpy will be probably more efficient.

Comment: @scls From above it does work? Are you passing True and False as booleans and not strings? If so that would cause it to fail.

Comment: @scls I'm confused...I wrote the function above to create both arrays using pretty much only stdlib which is fast?

Comment: No sorry it doesn't work with binary it raises `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`. `df.columns Index([False, True], dtype='object')` but `df_new.columns Index([True], dtype='object')`. For loops are slower than Numpy calls (C)

Comment: That error is due to the comment I made above that the index of the dataframe you create in the binary case is made of boolean values rather than strings.  Is it necessary to have an index or column names with non-string keys?

Comment: The binary df only have 1 index (not 2) and 1 column (not 2). I don't understand why